# strange UTF-8 byte encoding issue with Rails, IE, PostgreSQL, delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, postgresql, utf-8, delayed-job

I'm seeing a relatively strange (and hard to diagnose) error with a combination of IE8, Rails 3.0.3, PostgreSQL and delayed_job.

I have a text area on one of my pages, and in the controller I delay a message with delayed_job which includes an object which has the content from the text area:

```
SomeMailer.delay.send_message(message)
```

This works fine on Chrome, FF, Safari.  However in IE8 *only*, and *only* when I actually enter text in the text area, and it looks like only when I enter a carriage return in the text area (I think), I get this error from the controller:

> invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

This appears to me to be when delayed_job is serializing the job to the database via ActiveRecord, that it doesn't like the character encoding in the newline (\r\n).  It's a bit hard to figure out because I don't know if this is an IE, Rails, delayed_job or Postgres issue.

**Side Note**: I'm getting this error locally, but it doesn't appear that this error appears on Heroku - so maybe they have their database configured better than I do?

**Environment**:

1. Rails 3.0.3
2. Ruby 1.9.2
3. Postgres 8.4 - encoding UTF8, collation en_US.UTF-8
4. delayed_job 2.1.4
5. IE 8

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting your encoding in the HTML that is being sent to IE8? e.g.:

```
<!doctype html>    
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
```

It's possible that the other browsers are working around the missing information and assuming UTF-8 when encoding the data from your text area.

Comment: Yup, sure enough my meta tag had a typo in it, should have been:  <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>

Comment: I should have pointed out that my example was from an HTML5 app, so the details are slightly different. I'm glad it worked out for you anyway!